# Sum One Column Across Only One Row?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I would like to SUM up one column, but based on different transaction types, and have those sums appear in one row only.

My SQL (SQL Server 2000) looks like this:

```
SELECT c.customername,
       CASE WHEN t.transactiontypekey IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) THEN SUM(t.tranamount) ELSE 0 END as 'Tot-Exp',
       CASE WHEN t.transactiontypekey IN (20,21,22,23,30,32,34,36) THEN SUM(t.tranamount) ELSE 0 END as 'Tot-Rev',
       CASE WHEN t.transactiontypekey IN (31,33,35,37) THEN SUM(t.tranamount) ELSE 0 END as 'Tot-Fee'
FROM customers c, transactions t
WHERE c.customerkey = t.customerkey
GROUP BY c.customername, t.transactiontypekey
ORDER BY c.customername
```

In the above SQL, the transaction types are broken out into Expenses, Revenue and Fees and the output from above is showing as:

```
customernameTot-Exp  Tot-Rev    Tot-Fee
CUSTOMER1   13.3900    .0000      .0000
CUSTOMER1     .0000 549.0000      .0000
CUSTOMER1     .0000    .0000    60.0000
CUSTOMER1     .0000    .0000      .0000
```

How can I get my output to look like:

```
customername     Tot-Exp   Tot-Rev  Tot-Fee
CUSTOMER1         13.390    549.00   60.000
```

one row per customer with all of the totals of the 't.tranamount' column in that one row only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sum the `CASE` expression itself;

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.transactiontypekey IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) THEN t.tranamount ELSE 0 END) as 'Tot-Exp',
```

And remove `t.transactiontypekey` from the the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I tried that and got this error: Server: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: did you remove the existing SUM in SUM(t.tranamount)

Comment: This is the correct answer. This type of query is known as a cross tabulation (or cross tab).

Comment: no I didnt.  :-(  Thank you for pointing that out!  This did in fact work very nicely!  Thanks!